# How can I change the generated path of my Gatsby blog post pages?

Tags: gatsby

By default my Gatsby urls are like `2018-09-06-hexagon`

Is there any way that they could become `/blog/2018/09/06/hexagon`?

Here is the relevant portion of my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const blogPost = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js')
    resolve(
      graphql(
        `
          {
            allMarkdownRemark(
              sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
              limit: 1000
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  fields {
                    slug
                  }
                  frontmatter {
                    title
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `
      ).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          console.log(result.errors)
          reject(result.errors)
        }


        // Create blog posts pages.
        const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges


        _.each(posts, (post, index) => {
          const previous =
            index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node
          const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node


          createPage({
            path: post.node.fields.slug,
            component: blogPost,
            context: {
              slug: post.node.fields.slug,
              previous,
              next,
            },
          })
        })
      })
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Did you mistag your question? Gatsby does what you configure it to do. What's your `gatsby-node.js` look like?

Comment: @coreyward https://github.com/dagda1/personal-blog/blob/master/gatsby-node.js how would gatsby-node help with this?

Comment: This is where the path is set for the blog post: https://github.com/dagda1/personal-blog/blob/master/gatsby-node.js#L47

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either update the slugs inside your blog post frontmatter to contain slashes where you want them, or you can transform the slug inside of `createPages`:

```
        // Create blog posts pages.
        const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges

        _.each(posts, (post, index) => {
          const previous =
            index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node
          const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node
          const blogPostPath = 
            `/blog/${post.node.fields.slug.replace(/-/g, "/")}`

          createPage({
            path: blogPostPath,
            component: blogPost,
            context: {
              slug: post.node.fields.slug,
              postPath: blogPostPath,
              previous,
              next,
            },
          })
        })
```